# Using Wakelock with Audio Service in flutter

Tags: flutter, wakelock, just-audio, audio-service

I have a requirement to give the user the option to keep specific screen in the app awake so the screen will not be switched off automatically in order to give the user the time to read the content. at the same time the application uses audio_service pluggin to play audio in the background.

The problem is when I enable the wake lock the audio_service stopped working in the background.

Any idea how to solve this conflict.

Comment: If audio_service stops working, you might want to submit a bug report.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.